# UWP: Retrieve correct file name/path from scale-based asset

Tags: image, uwp, windows-10-universal

Currently I retrieve the file path from XAML in this way:

```
var myFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, fileImage.File);
```

Because in XAML the file name is e.g. `icon.png` and not `icon.scale-150.png` it doesn't find the image, when I want to read it into a stream. How can I retrieve the correct file name/path from the scale-based asset?

It has to take the general path and convert it into a scale-based path. Is there a method for this? I can't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the icon.png is located in the Assets folder, you can just retrieve the URI by using the ms-appx protocol, in this way:

var file = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/icon.png");

This will retrieve the icon with the right scale, based on the device.

Comment: How can I read the file in? Before I used `OpenStreamForReadAsync()`, but now I haven't managed to read the file with the correct path.

Comment: OK, now I found this way: `var sf = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(file);
                    using (Stream s = await sf.OpenStreamForReadAsync()){ // do something }`. How do I know which icon size the system takes? Now it seems that it doesn't take the scale, which would fit the best for the size requirements. Instead it takes the scale, which is set for the platform/app. So I have to make the icon bigger, according to my size requirements.

Comment: How do you handle the case if the Uri contains a `ms-appx:///` path or a "normal" path? Using the ms-appx protocol is the only way for retrieving the correct scale?

Comment: @testing AFAIK, yes, the ms-appx protocol is the only way to retrieve the correct scale, since it exists for that purpose. If you want to take the scale that best fit your size requirements, then you should use the full-name of the file (you must load it explicitly).